# How can I turn [1..10] into [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] in calc?

Tags: calc

When playing around with data in `calc`, I often want to generate a vector from an interval.

How can I easily create a vector from just a start point, end point & step value.

Something like `1 <RET> 10 <RET> 1 MAKE-VECTOR` to give me `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

<kbd>v x 10 RET</kbd> should do it. Uses `calc-index`.